# Stripe - How to dynamically charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a pricing table that includes 3 plans with different prices.

I'm trying to charge the user the amount related to the plan they select. Is there a way to dynamically fetch the amount on the server side using PHP when the user selects a plan and the form is submitted? I'm not sure how to pass the dollar amount safely and charge them.

***Edit: added PHP code***

Here is the PHP i'm working with which pulls the dollar amount from the form which is inside a value. eg. "value='20'. My problem with the current setup is anyone can change that value.

```
<?php
require 'lib/Stripe.php';

if ($_POST) {
Stripe::setApiKey("insert_key_here");

try {
if (empty($_POST['email']))
    throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
  if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
    throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
  Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $_POST['posted'] * 100,
                              "currency" => "usd",
                              "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
             "description" => $_POST['email']));
  $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
     </div>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, there are many potential ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing a an additional `<input type="hidden">`-field or a drop-down along with your form that contains the tier *name*.  This can map to an enumeration (or map) on your backend that has the actual `amount`s associated with each tier.  Then you don't run the risk of someone screwing with your Javascript and changing what they have to pay.